# Route traffic between two IPsec tunnels

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan, backend, libreswan

I run a backend on DO infrastructure, call it site **Yvi**, that connects to a third party site **Prov** via an IPsec tunnel, with this libreswan config:

```
conn prov-client
  ...
  right=$YVI_IP
  rightsourceip=10.31.3.1
  rightsubnet=10.31.3.0/28
  left=$PROV_IP
  leftsubnet=10.70.0.36/28
```

**Prov** has a server running on `10.70.0.37`, and I'm able to interact with it from **Yvi**.

My problem is that I'm setting up a local dev environment (an Ubuntu box in another network), and each time I make a change I have to deploy to **Yvi** because only from there can I reach the API in **Prov**. I'd like to avoid this by connecting **Local** to **Yvi** and route that traffic to **Prov** to be able to reach the API in **Prov** from **Local** and ease development.

I connect **Local** to **Yvi** as a road warrior with the following conf:

```
conn remote-dev-client
  ...
  left=$YVI_IP
  leftsubnet=10.31.3.0/28
  right=%any
  rightaddresspool=10.31.4.1-10.31.4.254
```

Connection is established successfully and from **Local** I can reach `10.31.3.1` on **Yvi**. What I want is to reach `10.70.0.37` in **Prov** from **Local**. The route to the `10.70.0.36/28` network is not added automatically, so I tried setting some `ip xfrm` and `ip route` rules manually on **Local**:

```
# Outgoing
ip xfrm policy add dst 10.70.0.37 src 10.31.4.1 dir out tmpl src $LOCAL_IP dst $YVI_IP proto esp spi $SPI reqid $REQID mode tunnel priority 100000

# Incoming
ip xfrm policy add dst 10.31.4.1 src 10.70.0.37 dir fwd tmpl src $YVI_IP dst $LOCAL_IP proto esp reqid $REQID mode tunnel priority 100000
ip xfrm policy add dst 10.31.4.1 src 10.70.0.37 dir in tmpl src $YVI_IP dst $LOCAL_IP proto esp reqid $REQID mode tunnel priority 100000

ip route add table 220 src 10.31.4.1 10.70.0.37 via $LOCAL_IP dev $LOCAL_IF proto static
```

I now run `ip xfrm monitor` on **Yvi** and then from **Local** ping `10.70.0.37`; I can see the packets arriving at **Yvi** (from the xfrm monitor in **Yvi**), but only the outgoing, not the response (as is seen if I ping 10.31.3.1, for example), suggesting that **Yvi** is receiving the traffic but not routing it to **Prov**? I really don't know how to interpret this.

I think I have to add routes in **Yvi** to route the traffic to the **Prov** API correctly, but adding similar rules to the ones above hasn't worked. I'd appreciate help in understanding what I'm missing, and what I'm doing wrong.

Suggestions for a different approach are also welcome, although the only way to connect to **Prov**, which I don't control, is through an IPsec tunnel from **Yvi**, which I do control.

Comment: To do that you'd need the route for your *local* on *prov* via *Yvi*, or NAT traffic on *Yvi* from *local* to *prov* as an IP already routed.  Or just do an ssh tunnel and deploy via Yvi from local to prov.

Comment: @JacobEvans I don't control Prov, so I wouldn't be able to set up the route to Local via Yvi. In that case, it would necessarily have to be NAT?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @JacobEvans, I solved it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with iptables NAT rules. The `ip xfrm` policies were not necessary. This is a small explanation of what I did, for someone who, as me, is not an expert:

From **Yvi** I am assigning the road warriors a `10.31.4.0/24` subnet, so a route for that network is automatically installed by the keying daemon (libreswan in my case) so I added NAT rules in **Yvi** (`/etc/ufw/before.rules`, since I am using UFW, but you could achieve the same with `iptables` directly):

```
*nat
-F
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# PRE 
-A PREROUTING -s 10.31.4.0/24 -d 10.31.3.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.70.0.37


# POST
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.31.4.0/24 -d 10.70.0.37 -j SNAT --to-source 10.31.3.1

COMMIT
```

The `*nat` tells iptables to apply the rules to the NAT table and the `COMMIT` actually saves the rules. The `-F` is just there for convenience, as UFW adds the rules on `ufw enable` but doesn't delete them on `ufw disable` so you end up with duplicates, hence the flush flag `-F`.

The `PREROUTING` rule applies to packets incoming from the road warrior subnet destined to `10.31.3.2`, and what it does is it changes the destination address to be `10.70.0.37` instead of `10.31.3.2`, effectively assigning that IP address to the **Prov** server, from the road warriors' perspective.

The `POSTROUTING` rule applies to packets incoming from the road warrior subnet about to go out to `10.70.0.37` (so, packets that just hit the prerouting rule), and changes their destination address from an address in `10.31.4.0/0` to `10.31.3.1`. This is necessary because I don't control the routes, server, or anything in **Prov**, so if **Prov** gets a request from the `10.30.4.0/24` subnet, it wouldn't know how to respond. But it does know `10.31.3.1`.

And that's it! Now I can reach **Prov** from **Local** via **Yvi** at `10.31.3.2`.

Comment: If you're trying to debug iptables, I found it helpful to add duplicate LOG rules before each rule you're debugging, something like this:
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.31.4.0/24 -d 10.70.0.37 -j LOG --log-prefix "SOME_IDENTIFIER"

and now you should be able to grep SOME_IDENTIFIER from syslog, and it'll show up every time the rule matches.